# PHP: Save only the changed part of a post to a database

Tags: php, optimization, diff

I have a website, where users can submit some text. Users can edit their posts and then save it. User can then go through all the changes he/she did to a post.

**Problem:**

 Whenever they edit a post, I want to keep the old one and the edited one(s), but i don't want to save the same part of the post many times.

**My Approach**

 At first I wanted to save the original post, and then save just the appended text, but the problem I'm having is, that the edited part of the post is not always at the end.

How should I solve that?

Comment: You're reinventing the `diff`/patch.  Take a look at how VCS works (git/svn/etc.).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding

Comment: Before going down this path, I would also make sure that you _really_ need this. Text is quite 'cheap' to store, and a typical post will probably not take up that much space. I imagine you need a TON of posts and edits before this becomes a problem on generic hardware.

Comment: Evert, if you want to also autosave at few keyboard strokes and have long text, then you surely need this. At least I do (and I found this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solve that with an algorithm that is specialized for such task, for example *diff and patch*. You either implement it your own, re-use an existing implementation or you use a software that is already finished that allows to store data in revisions.